# show.html.erb rendering as plain text mime time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am brand spankin new to ruby and rails.  I've gone through the rails for zombies tutorial and a couple others.

I generated a default rails app using the tools on my web host.

I got rails wired to a database and am able to display a page with values from it.

From all my searching **I believe that just naming my view files *.html.erb should be enough to make them render with a mime type for html.**

**The problem is the page shows up with a Content-Type: text/plain.**

Here's what I have

config/routes.rb

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :enrollapplications
end
```

app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper :all # include all helpers, all the time
  protect_from_forgery # See ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection for details
end
```

app/controllers/enrollapplications_controller.rb

```
class EnrollapplicationsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @enrollapp = Enrollapplication.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Enrollment Application</title>
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
 </head>
 <body>
   <%= yield %>   
 </body>
</html>
```

app/views/enrollapplications/show.html.erb

```
   <h3>show stuff</h3>

   <h1><%= @enrollapp.firstName %></h1>
```

curl -I example.com/Application/enrollapplications/1

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 28 Jul 2013 17:37:36 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Feel free to point and laugh at my mistakes.

Comment: **I generated a default rails app using the tools on my web host.**  

This is where the problems lies, you need to elaborate on this.

Comment: What URL are you calling via `curl -l`? Ruby isn't like PHP (for example) - if you are requesting a `.erb` file and it is web-accessible, it won't cause the Ruby application to execute.

Comment: My host has a rails admin tool that generates a stubbed out rails app and deploys it.  All it asks for is a name.

Comment: Also, it looks like the version (out of my control) is Rails 2.3.18.

Comment: @Diver You might try running Rails locally for tinkering, in order to eliminate potential variables that could cause issues like this. It's definitely not expected or common behavior. Do you see the `<%` tags in the curled response?

Comment: I'm working on getting it running in a local environment but having troubles getting it going.  (nothing I cant handle)

The curl shows the correct rendered html (no <%) just with a content type of text/plain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Linux admin for my host said they are running a version of Mongrel where this is a known bug.

He put a newer version of mongrel.rb in my /config/initializers and that solved the problem.